# Japanese character selected from suggestions on keyboard in objectivec

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have an issue, where I am trying to enter Japanese characters using the keyboard in iPhone in UITextField.

The issue, is I have implemented `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method, which gets called properly. However, when I use Japanese characters, using Japanese keyboard, there is a suggestion bar on top of the keyboard. If I select any of the word from that suggestion bar, it gets replaced. I want to identify if the user selected from the suggestion bar that was shown or the word was typed. Is there any way by which I can find if, the word has been typed or selected from the suggestion list?

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Anyone? A way to get known when the word is selected from the suggestion or typed from keyboard?

Comment: To anyone who is searching for this. It can be done to one extent. What I had done is find whether the suggestion bar is displayed. This can be done by finding the UIKeyboardCandidateBar in the UIView. This will confirm, that the language supported is that of supporting the suggestions. If it appears, then we do appropriate action. However, the question still remains open, -- How do we know which character is clicked.